# Docker Swarm Windows Server container not accesible from browser when run in a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am attempting to run a prototype of a microservice deployment (at this point just for R&D purposes). I have made a very basic API endpoint and used docker-compose in visual studio to create the container. The API code is as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Microservice Test Successful 2");

        return response;
    }
}
```

And the deployed container has the following details (second one on the list):

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
31d4d7f15d3e        testmicroservice:latest   "C:\\ServiceMonitor.e…"   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours                                testservice.1.ttt25efcq418xbsu7vqksl94p
816c526ef9f3        testmicroservice          "cmd /c 'start /B C:…"    16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:8785->80/tcp   dockercompose2417227251495589316_gdms.testmicroservice_1
```

I can quite merrily access this in my browser on the published port and get back the expected result from the API:

[image: Screen shot from browser]

I have attempted to deploy this same image as a docker service (with swarm mode active in docker) and have mapped a different port to access it:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                     PORTS
m3wfea6n9anl        testservice         replicated          1/1                 testmicroservice:latest   *:5050->80/tcp
```

The service appears to be running correctly and the container for this task also appears to be running fine (it is the first of the two containers from the snippet above.

For some reason when i attempt to access the same endpoint but with the new port (again on localhost in my browser), i get "unable to connect".

The full docker service details are below.

```
    [
    {
        "ID": "m3wfea6n9anligjrrihbi03vt",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 500
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2018-10-04T16:19:17.2891599Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2018-10-04T16:19:17.2921526Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "testservice",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "testmicroservice:latest",
                    "Init": false,
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {},
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 5050,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 5050,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 80,
                    "PublishedPort": 5050,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "ylj65tghq4ek1ewmtysaitmcx",
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.31/16"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The dockerfile for the image is this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

Any suggestions as to what I may have missed would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working now and thought I would share what I did in case anyone else faces the same.

I believe the issue I was facing was due to a couple of factors:

1) The Routing Mesh not being fully supported for Windows Server Containers/Hosts on Docker CE

2) A miss-match between the operating system kernels between the container and the host which again caused issues with the ingress network and publishing ports (although it did not throw up any warning/error to indicate this fact).

**How I got it working:**

1) Created an 1803 Windows Server VM and installed Docker EE Basic (which comes free with Windows Server 2016 and above). I believe running a VM on 1709 would have also worked). If you have a VM running Windows Server 2016+ you can install the EE Basic version of docker following the instructions from the [Docker Website](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/) (make sure to update it to the latest version).

2) Changed the Dockerfile I was using to create the image to use the 1803 version of microsoft/aspnet:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

(if you are using a 1709 Windows Server VM then it would have been:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

3) Deployed the new image to the VM.

4) Set up swarm mode on the server:

```
Docker Swarm Init
```

5) Deployed the image as a Service:

```
Docker Service Create --name testservice --publish 3000:80 testmicroservice
```

Following these steps I now have a fully functional swarm running on a multi node cluster witha number of different replicated services.

Hope this helps.